# Unable to Restore MySQL 8.0 Dump in Docker Container

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm facing difficulties restoring a MySQL 8.0 dump into a Docker container. I've tried multiple approaches, but none seem to work. I suspect it's due to issues with password handling or identification.

Here's the command I'm using to try to restore the dump:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /home/vagrant/projects/util/services/docker-compose.yml exec -T mysql-8.0 mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/conf.d/backup.cnf < /home/vagrant/services/data/mysql-5.7-dump.sql
```

However, I'm encountering errors related to password security or unidentified passwords. Like:

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insec' at line 1.

When I tried this command below to show databases, I didn't get an error, but the databases that I have. However, I was unable to use something similar to restore the dump.

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /home/vagrant/projects/util/services/docker-compose.yml exec -T mysql-8.0 mysql --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/conf.d/backup.cnf -e "show databases"
```

My `docker-compose.yml` is this:

```
mysql-8.0:
    image: mysql:8.0.32
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "12345678"
    volumes:
        - "/home/vagrant/services/data/mysql-8.0:/var/lib/mysql"
        - "/home/vagrant/services/config/mysql-8.0:/etc/mysql/conf.d"
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
```

My `backup.cnf` is looks like this:

```
[client]
user="root"
password="12345678"
```

Here are my observations and attempts:

- Password Handling: I suspect there might be an issue with how passwords are handled in my command. I've tried using `MYSQL_PWD`, but I'm unsure if it's correctly passed to the container.
- Command Structure: I'm not entirely sure if the structure of my command is correct for restoring a dump into a MySQL container. It's possible that there might be a mistake in how I'm specifying the command or the file path.

I'm seeking guidance on the correct approach to restore a MySQL 8.0 dump into a Docker container.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you *sure* that dump is valid SQL? Have you had a look at it? That error has nothing to do with the advisory at the end.

Comment: As a note, you may want to boot the container, then restore using the `mysql` client or MySQL Workbench attached to it. This gives you more control over the restore process.

Comment: @tadman Thank you very much, the dump was exactly at the beginning of the file, but I hadn't seen it before.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, upon closer inspection, I realized that the issue was within the SQL dump file itself. At the beginning of the dump, there was a message "[Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insec..." which I overlooked initially, assuming it was unrelated. Your suggestion prompted me to revisit the file, and upon identifying this warning, I rectified the situation accordingly. I appreciate your guidance.

Thanks again for your valuable input.